# Resizable child pane

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have created main container FXML file, and separate home FXML file. I am trying to add home file to main container. main container has one border pane and I am adding home FXML to center of border pane, but when I an maximizing pane take only preferred space, but not space available

maincontainer

```
 <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="553.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.tensorApplications.jBills.controllers.Controller">
   <children>
      <MenuBar layoutY="3.0" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Windows">
            <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Home" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="AddProducts" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Analytics" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" layoutY="22.0" prefHeight="378.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="22.0">
         <bottom>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="22.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </bottom>
         <left>
            <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="509.0" prefWidth="138.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="home" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getHome" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="196.0" text="Home">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="200.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="204.0" text="Button" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="198.0" text="Button" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="166.0" text="Button" />
               </children>
               <BorderPane.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </BorderPane.margin>
            </VBox>
         </left>
         <center>
            <FlowPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FF0000;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

child container

```
<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="500" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="264.00000915527346" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="113.20000610351562" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="225.00000610351563" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="36.79998779296875" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="183.60001525878909" minHeight="22.39996337890625" prefHeight="136.00001220703123" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="124.00002441406252" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="113.60000000000002" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn maxWidth="42.0" prefWidth="42.0" resizable="false" text="Sr.No" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="85.5999755859375" text="HSN/SAC" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="pID" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="ProductName" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Wt/Ps" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Qty" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Rate" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="TaxableAmt" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="GST">
               <columns>
                  <TableColumn maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" resizable="false" text="\%" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Amt" />
               </columns>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Total" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Working with SceneBuilder will definitely simplify the work :), but you need to be very careful with all the attributes it generates. Particularly in FXML file, don't include any attribute unless it is really required.

I can observe the same in your FXML code. There are lot of unnecessary attributes which you can eliminate. In fact that will fix your issue.

Few points you can consider:

- Understand the impact of using min/max width/height with Infinity/-Infinity
- Remove unnecessary constraints if it is not required.
- Understand how each layout behaves. Choosing the correct layout will really simplify the work.
- If you want your application to be resizable, try minimizing the usage of prefWidth/height and let the layout take care of it.

I tried to do some rework on the fxmls you provided. You can check the below code for reference and see what can be done to your exact requirement.

[image]

MainContainer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.tensorApplications.jBills.controllers.Controller">
    <top>
        <MenuBar >
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Windows">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Home" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="AddProducts" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Analytics" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" >
            <left>
                <VBox prefWidth="138.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <children>
                        <Button fx:id="home" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getHome" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="196.0" text="Home"/>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="204.0" text="Button" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="198.0" text="Button" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="166.0" text="Button" />
                    </children>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets topRightBottomLeft="5"/>
                    </padding>
                </VBox>
            </left>
            <center>

            </center>
        </BorderPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Child Container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<GridPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" fillWidth="true"/>
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" fillHeight="true"/>
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <TableView>
            <columns>
                <TableColumn maxWidth="42.0" prefWidth="42.0" resizable="false" text="Sr.No"/>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="85.5999755859375" text="HSN/SAC"/>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="pID"/>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="ProductName"/>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Wt/Ps"/>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Qty"/>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Rate"/>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="TaxableAmt"/>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="GST">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" resizable="false" text="\%"/>
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Amt"/>
                    </columns>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Total"/>
            </columns>
            <columnResizePolicy>
                <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"/>
            </columnResizePolicy>
        </TableView>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```